# Ionic 3 : How to use cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm trying to use this cordova plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter.

Here my code :

```
...
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var cordova;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      alert(cordova.plugins.sqlitePlugin);
    });
  }
```

The problem is, what-ever I do, `sqlitePlugin` is always `undefined` :/
However `cordova.plugins` is an object.

I also tried `alert((<any>window).plugins.sqlitePlugin);` but the result is the same.

I'm running in an Nexus 5X Android 8 device.

I have installed the plugin this way : `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlcipher-adapter --save` as a standard cordova plugin.

Any helps would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 23):

After several hours, the correct way to use the plugin was : `(<any>window).sqlitePlugin`

Hope it could helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Your solution save my day.

Comment: Must be the correct answer. If you debug the `(<any>window)` object you will see all available plugins.

Answer (score 4):

It's work for me

```
window["pluginName"].pluginFunction
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it as

```
window["pluginName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`@awesome-cordova-plugins` tends to be the best way to incorporate Cordova plugins into an Ionic app - they have Angular-friendly wrappers for a large variety of plugins, eg [SQLite](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite)